# Calculate $\sqrt [3] {7+5\sqrt {2}}+\sqrt [3] {7-5\sqrt {2}}$

Tags: real-numbers, radicals

i need help.
I tried but I could not(real numbers).

Comment: Yes, they are real numbers assuming you allow cube roots of negative numbers.

Comment: @RossMillikan - Do you mean, "assuming you only consider the real cube root of real numbers"? This applies equally to positive and negative numbers - there is absolutely nothing special about negative numbers with respect to *cube* roots.

Comment: @mathguy Can't speak for him but I think he means assuming the numbers aren't complex, in which case there are three cube roots if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @theREALyumdub -  I was interested in the reference to "negative numbers" which doesn't seem to mean anything in this context. (Besides the fact the OP from the very beginning said "real numbers" so I really didn't understand why the comment was needed to begin with.)

Comment: Some definitions of exponentiation only allow integer powers of negative numbers.  One can do odd roots of negative real numbers consistently. Assuming you allow those, your numbers are real, even though $7-5\sqrt 2 \lt 0$

Comment: I've seen $a^{1/odd} $ being defined and alternately not defined for negative a but I've never seen $\sqrt[odd]{a} $ not being defined.

Answer (score 5):

Let $a$ and $b$ be the two terms of the sum. Note that they are both real numbers, and $a^3 + b^3 = 14$ while $ab = -1$.

$$a^3+b^3 = (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2) = (a+b)((a+b)^2-3ab)$$

Write $x=a+b$ , so $14 = x(x^2+3)$ or $x^3 + 3x -14 =0$. This equation has only one real solution. Solve it and you are done.

Comment: @mathguy: Neat solution. But I am confused by the question itself, as it seems to be inverted. For example if the problem were  to find a real root of $x^3+3x-14=0$ the expression in the title of the question would be acceptable as an answer. So what you have found is an equation that has the given  number as a root: or it could be interpreted as explicitly proving given number is an algebraic integer. Is this what is wanted?

Comment: @PVanchinathan - Fair point. The question can also be asked as "calculate 2." My proof calculates it - it shows it equals the number in the problem statement. However, in these cases the problem is generally read as "simplify ...." (which is somewhat different from "calculate"). In that sense, 2 is indeed simpler than the original expression, even though they are obviously the same value.

Comment: @mathguy: Looking at the paucity of words in the question we have to guess what this person wants.  Should we downvote the question or ask for clarification?  But we can't help if the person does not have a clear idea of what is needed.

Comment: I don't think the problem statement is unclear. If a question asks "calculate $\sqrt{8} - 2\sqrt{2}$, the problem is of the same nature; yet the answer ($0$) wouldn't raise an eyebrow. I don't see why this is different.